# How to create a relative max-length constraint on Many-to-Many field in django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, manytomanyfield

I'm working on an educational django project as an intern and have got trouble with a database constraint on length of many-to-many field.
I have a Trip model that contains a capacity field which is an IntegerField and a passeger field which is many-to-many. So I want to create a constraint that number of passengers of a trip never get more than trip's capacity. Can anybody help me with this problem?

I have tied the CheckConstraints but faild to handle it with join attribute.

```py
class Trip(models.Model):
    WAITING_STATUS = 'wa'
    CLOSED_STATUS = 'cl'
    IN_ROUTE_STATUS = 'in'
    DONE_STATUS = 'dn'
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (WAITING_STATUS, 'waiting'),
        (CLOSED_STATUS, 'closed'),
        (IN_ROUTE_STATUS, 'in route'),
        (DONE_STATUS, 'done')
    ]
    source = gis_models.PointField()
    destination = gis_models.PointField()
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    passengers = models.ManyToManyField(Member, through="Companionship", related_name='partaking_trips')
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, through="TripGroups")
    car_provider = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='driving_trips', null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(20)])
    start_estimation = models.DateTimeField()
    end_estimation = models.DateTimeField()
    trip_description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)


class Companionship(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trip = models.ForeignKey(Trip, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source = gis_models.PointField()
    destination = gis_models.PointField()
```

I got error "joined field references are not permitted in this query" when tried to migrate.

Comment: I'm not sure this is something that can or even should be built into the model. This sort of thing should be done when you try and enter/save new data - i.e. when you add a new passenger to the trip, it should validate that there is room for it.

Comment: @urbanespaceman Thanks for your help, but I have already tried that; The problem is this may cause race condition.

Comment: Ah, OK. I guess then even the clean methods are no good for this case then. Looks like you'll need to override the save method for the model to do it then - or do you have a valid case where that could also create a race condition?

Comment: @urbanespaceman I have thinked about transactional methods. Seems it works but I'm looking for a database level solution.

Comment: Can you use atomic requests?

Comment: You can use @transaction.atomic above a function to make it atomic. transaction can be imported from django.db

Comment: Yes, I know. I was asking if that might help with your race condition problems ... otherwise I'm out of suggestions, sorry.